# A new object is detached from a data context

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, backgroundworker

I added a new object in background worker, The new object was added successfully, But if try to delete it I got an error because the new object was detached from data context.

**Background Worker Do_Work Event**

```
private void _anotherThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        testdbEntities context = new testdbEntities();

        _item = new item();
        this.txbItemName.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate () { _item.name = this.txbItemName.Text; }));

        context.item.Add(_item);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.ocItems.Add(_item)));

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Delete Button** (on the main thread)
,If I attached a new object it works

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Item _selectedItem = (Item)lbItems.SelectedItem;

        if (_context.Entry(_selectedItem).State == EntityState.Detached)
            _context.Item.Attach(_selectedItem);

        _context.Item.Remove(_selectedItem);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My question is why the new object not attached to data context ? Should I attche every new object added in background worker ?

Thanks

Comment: How/Where do you manage your contexts?  Was it the same context?  You do know each thread (bgw) should have its own?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, In the bgw I initiate a new instance of my db context

Comment: Can you please update your question and add in the relevant code segment for where that new object is created?

Comment: @devlincarnate I updated my questions.

Comment: It seems obvious: there are 2 datacontexts here. An entry can only belong to one.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If I want to add a new object in another thread I should initiate a new instance of dbcontext

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif: Yes.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Back to my questions, Should I attache every new object added in background worker ?

Comment: You should attach an entry when it is not attached with _this_ context. But your question is incomplete, how did it get into lbItems ?

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend *not* using Entities, especially tracked entities in your control bindings. A tracked entity should live only as long as it's DbContext, and any DbContext you create should have a defined lifetime scope. (Dispose them)

So in your background job, new-ing up a DbContext should be scoped within a `using` block to ensure it's disposed.

```
private void _anotherThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using(testdbEntities context = new testdbEntities())
    {
        _item = new item();
        this.txbItemName.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate () { _item.name = this.txbItemName.Text; }));

        context.item.Add(_item);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.ocItems.Add(_item)));

        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Detach(_item); 
    }
}
```

Then when you go to use the Delete button, if you are dealing with a long-lived DbContext (_context) then check the context to see if that entity is already tracked, if not, attach it (or a proxy to it) and perform your delete. If it is already tracked, delete the tracked one:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Item _selectedItem = (Item)lbItems.SelectedItem;

    Item existingItem = _context.Item.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == _selectedItem.ItemId);
    if (existingItem != null)
        _context.Item.Remove(existingItem);
    else
    {
        _context.Item.Attach(_selectedItem);
        _context.Item.Remove(_selectedItem);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Checking the `.Local` does not hit the database, it just looks for a tracked entity reference for that Id. If one is found, we remove that. If not, we can attach ours and remove it to issue the Delete.

Long-lived DbContexts can cause you issues because through various operations, an entity with the ID of the list item might be tracked already, so using the attached/detached state of a stale copy that was stored in a List control won't be reliable.

If the list Item returns the ID of the entity to delete rather than an untracked entity reference you can still efficiently delete the entity:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int itemId = lbItems.SelectedItem.ItemId; // Where a simple view model was put in the SelectedItem, not an entity.

    Item existingItem = _context.Item.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == itemId);
    if (existingItem != null)
        _context.Item.Remove(existingItem);
    else
    { 
        var tempItem = new Item { ItemId = itemId }; 
        _context.Item.Attach(tempItem);
        _context.Item.Remove(tempItem);
    }
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Not much different, but removes the assumption that your list item contains a complete entity when it really doesn't. The list view model can also be a lot more compact than the entire entity, requiring less memory & time to load. The risk of dealing with attached and detached entities is that these entities still need to be assessed against a context in case another entity for that ID is already tracked (due to edits, etc.) and for operations like edits, these entities can be stale. Other applications/users/processes could have updated the data behind the entity. By attaching and doing something like editing and saving changes, that entity only held that user's last known state which can, and will overwrite changes made by other users. When dealing with concurrent edits, it's preferable to load the entity, check the row version or timestamp to see if it's been modified since last retrieved, and handle the scenario if/where it has. You can also run into issues where the underlying record could have been deleted since your current session retrieved it, in which case an attach, update, and SaveChanges would result in an "expected 1, found 0" error or similar. (Not sure, but that could happen in the Delete scenario as well.)